# Finding A power B using BigInteger and using recursion

Tags: java, recursion, biginteger

This is the piece of code in Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.math.*;

class power1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    long a=in.nextLong();
    BigInteger b=in.nextBigInteger();
    long res=power(a,b);
    System.out.println(res);
}

public static long power(long x,BigInteger n) {

    int b=(int)(Math.pow(10,9)+7);
    long m;
    if (n.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0)
        return 1;
    if(n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)==0)
        return x;
    if ((n.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0))
    {
        m = power(x,n.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
        return (m * m)%b;
    } 
    else return (x * power(x,n.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)))%b);

}

}
```

This is should work for any value of b considering that its a BigInteger.
But when i enter very large value of b ,i get errors as

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.MutableBigInteger.divideKnuth(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.BigInteger.remainderKnuth(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.BigInteger.remainder(Unknown Source)
    at java.math.BigInteger.mod(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Don't use recursion.

Comment: What big number ? since you divid by 2, this might take some call to get to 1 leading to this stackoverflow (and leading you on SO). This is a lot of BigInteger to store in memory

Comment: FYI: `n.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO)==0` is better written as `!n.testBit(0)`, and `n.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2))` is better written as `n.shiftRight(1)`. Performs much better.

Comment: Question: Why are you trying to raise a `long` value to a `BigInteger` exponent, and only returning result as a `long`? If the base is 1, result is 1 no matter the exponent. If base is 2, the result will overflow the supported range of a `long` result for an exponent value of 63, and you hardly need a `BigInteger` to that kind of value. For bases higher than 2, the result will overflow `long` at even smaller exponent values. Your method makes no sense.

Comment: But if i dont use Recursion then the computation will go up by a lot of factor .Variable b can be anything.

Comment: @RickySterling You asked how to avoid stack overflow error when performing too many recursions. The answer is to use a loop or some other means, not recursion.

Comment: Andreas Variable 'a' has the limit equivalent to that of long so i thought why to use BigInteger for that

Comment: @Andreas this thought occurred to me...But is there a better way to perform exponentiation?

Comment: I was talking about `res`, not `a` aka `x`. Example: What do you think `power(3, 80)` is? Answer: `1.478e+38`. That is twice as many digits of precision as `long` can hold, i.e. `long` cannot represent that result. Since your exponent is a `BigInteger`, it must be to support values greater than `9223372036854775807` (`long.MAX_VALUE`), but you can't even handle `80`, so what do you think `power(3, 9223372036854775807)` is? In short, what's the point of making exponent a `BigInteger`, when you can't even handle values outside the range of `byte` (max. 127)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement the following algorithm:

```
recursivePower(base, exp):
    if (exp == 0) 
        return 1;
    if (exp == 1)
        return base;
    if (exp%2 == 0) {
        temp = recursivePower(base, exp/2);
        return temp*temp;
    temp = recursivePower(base, (exp-1)/2);
    return temp*temp*base;
```

This will drastically reduce the number of calls you're using. Another thing is enlarging the size of the stack. Run your application with `java Test -Xss2048k` - try different sizes.

And last but not the least use BigInteger all the time.

```
public static BigInteger recursivePower (BigInteger base, BigInteger exp) {
    if (exp.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) 
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    if (exp.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0)
        return base;
    if (exp.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 0) {
        BigInteger temp = recursivePower(base, exp.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2)));
        return temp.multiply(temp);
    }
    BigInteger temp = recursivePower(base, (exp.subtract(BigInteger.valueOf(1)).divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2))));
    return temp.multiply(temp).multiply(base);
}

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println(recursivePower(BigInteger.valueOf(2), BigInteger.valueOf(80)).toString());
 }
```

Comment: it wont work..there are lot of glitches in the code.

Comment: @RickySterling why won't it work? It's a correct algorithm. You can convert  the returned value to long outside the function - single-responsibility.

Comment: @xenteros...if possible post the whole program using main().I am writing a program for a competition .Its to be compiled using online compiler.

Comment: @RickySterling what are you exptected to return? Should I print the result of 2^80?

Comment: @RickySterling I added printing. The result is ok according to wolfram alpha

Comment: @RickySterling just in case it's helpful please mark it as solution.

Comment: Yeah the code is correct .But when exp is very large like 3423543546542 and base is like 534654 ...It does not display or it freezes..

Comment: Of course it does. Such huge calculations are very time consuming. Give it some time.

Comment: @RickySterling, just see how long it takes to loop every Long values possibles `for(long l = 0; l < Long.MAX_VALUE; ++l){}`. So of course the operation you asked will take some times.

Comment: @AxelH I would mention that there should be anything inside the loop, as the compiler might optimize this loop :) still a good point as always

Comment: @xenteros, indeed !

Comment: @AxelH this starts to be too chatty, but I remember from embedded systems lessons, that it was quite tough to make a long loop which would be optimized by the compiler. Even incrementing a number and printing it later might get optimized by just assigning the result value by the compiler.